# SIGSEGV on Boost UDP socket close - tcache_get at malloc.c

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I have no idea where this problem might come from:
(Debugging with GDB):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of '[Thread 0x7ffff5e68700 (LWP 24945) exited]
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
```

Thread 1 "random_walkerta" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
tcache_get (tc_idx=1) at malloc.c:2943

**StackTrace:**

```
#0  tcache_get (tc_idx=1) at malloc.c:2943
#1  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=31) at malloc.c:3050
#2  0x00007ffff6ec154c in operator new(unsigned long) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6f56dbf in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff6f584bb in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00005555555bee66 in boost::system::system_error::what (
    this=0x5555558a1bf0) at /usr/include/boost/system/system_error.hpp:70
#6  0x00007ffff6eba8ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff6ec0d3a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff6ebfd59 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007ffff6ec0708 in __gxx_personality_v0 ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00007ffff6888763 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#11 0x00007ffff688907d in _Unwind_Resume ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#12 0x00005555555cb8d6 in boost::asio::detail::do_throw_error (err=..., 
    location=0x555555610dba "close")
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/throw_error.ipp:37
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#13 0x00005555555cb741 in boost::asio::detail::throw_error (err=..., 
    location=0x555555610dba "close")
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/throw_error.hpp:42
#14 0x00005555555de022 in boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::udp, boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp> >::close (
    this=0x555555887ea0) at /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:356
#15 0x00005555555d7ebe in Vast::net_overhearing_handler::handle_close (
    this=0x555555889490) at net_overhearing_handler.cpp:160
#16 0x00005555555d7e4c in Vast::net_overhearing_handler::close (
    this=0x555555889490) at net_overhearing_handler.cpp:141
#17 0x00005555555c9b85 in Vast::net_overhearing::stop (this=0x5555558870e0)
    at net_overhearing.cpp:88
#18 0x00005555555ba77f in Vast::VASTnet::~VASTnet (this=0x55555587f180, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at VASTnet.cpp:63
#19 0x000055555556ca7a in Vast::destroyNet (net=0x55555587f180)
    at VASTVerse.cpp:93
#20 0x000055555556d036 in Vast::VASTVerse::~VASTVerse (this=0x55555587e4c0, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at VASTVerse.cpp:196
#21 0x000055555556bce4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe598)
    at random_walkertalker.cpp:266
```

The setup is a follows:
I have a Boost UDP socket running on seperate thread io_service, listening for packets. Everything works according to expectation until I try to shutdown the program, UDP socket and io_service. I am guessing I am not correctly shutting something down.

Here is the code for shutting down the UDP and io_services:

```
if (_io_service != NULL) {
   _io_service->reset();
   _udp->close();                 //This line is giving the error (160)  


   _io_service->stop();
   _iosthread->join();
}
```

Starting up, I do the following:

```
_udp = new ip::udp::socket(*_io_service);
_udp->open(ip::udp::v4());

_udp->async_receive_from(
  boost::asio::buffer(_buf, VAST_BUFSIZ), _remote_endpoint_,
  boost::bind(&net_overhearing_handler::handle_input, this,
  boost::asio::placeholders::error,
  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

_iosthread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, io_service));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

```
 _io_service->reset();
```

because as per the reference [io_service::reset](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html)

> This function **must not be called** while there are any unfinished calls
>   to the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions.

It seems `run` method works in thread when you call `restart`.

You don't need to call this method to stop `io_service::run` method. All pending operations in `run` will be cancelled by calling `_io_service->stop();` then `run` stops and your thread also terminates.